# Toggle a sort function in React

Tags: reactjs, function, sorting, toggle

I'm created a table that display prices and a function to sort them but i can't figure out how to toggle between ascending and descending.

```
...//my states
      this.compareBy.bind(this);
      this.sortBy.bind(this);
  };

  compareBy(key) {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }


  sortBy(key) {
    let arrayCopy = [...this.state.data];
    arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
    this.setState({data: arrayCopy});
  }

 <th  onClick={() => this.sortBy('name')}>Name</th>
```

Here is the function of my code.

Comment: toggle some multiplier (1/-1) or flag in state, use in compareBy to condifionally reverse returned result

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state variable to indicate whether sorting should be done ascending or descending and update the `compareBy` function accordingly.

For example, if you name the state variable `sortAscending` (`boolean`), you can update `compareBy` to look something like this:

```js
compareBy(key) {
  const { sortAscending } = this.state;
  return function (a, b) {
    if (a[key] < b[key]) return sortAscending ? -1 : 1;
    if (a[key] > b[key]) return sortAscending ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
  };
}
```

Then add a button somewhere to toggle `sortAscending` or update it in successive clicks of the sort-by-name button.